# How can I create a button with an icon on the top right under the appbar on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to create a button under the appbar (navbar) with a button not too big just normal size but I couldn't. It needs to be on top right and icon will be on the right like "Categories(List Icon)"

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Please put the code in your question.

Comment: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children:<Widget>[

                  Align(alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.view_list),

                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Categories()));},
                  ),)
                ],
              ),
    ],
          ),

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how exactly you want it to be. As mentioned you can use [`endDrawer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/endDrawer.html)
or else, like in the screenshot, you can do something like this,

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Category Demo')),
      body: Column(children: [
        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
          Container(
            width: 130.0,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Categories()));
              },
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text("Categories"),
                    Icon(Icons.menu),
                  ]
               ),
            ),
          )
        ])
      ]),
    );
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

You can try endDrawer in Scaffold from this example:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/endDrawer.html

Comment: Yes I need that view_list icon exactly on that place or below If I could create that I would directly open the category page